# Divergent sequences whose sum diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are there any divergent sequences whose sum also diverges? Can anyone please explain with an example? Thank you.

Comment: $1,-1,1,-1,...$. This sequence diverges and obviously its sum also diverges.

Comment: What about $\;\{1,2,3,...,n,...\}\;$ ?

Comment: What do you mean with "divergent sequences whose sum also diverges" ?Most of the so called divergent series have a partial sum which diverges. I want to point out the fact that the sum mentioned by @KittyL diverges but it's partial sum doesn't (it's always 0 or 1 depending if you sum an odd or an even number of terms).

Comment: @Renato "diverge" is the opposite of "converge." A sequence that alternates between 0 and 1 does not converge, hence it diverges.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of every divergent sequence diverges. An infinite sum can only converge if its terms converge to 0, and even that is not enough. For example, $1/n$ as $n\to\infty$ converges to 0 but its sum diverges.

Answer (score 1):

The n-th term test for divergence of a series is "If $x_n$ does not converge to zero, then $\sum_n x_n$ does not exist." Thus, if $x_n$ diverges, it does not converge to zero and $\sum_n x_n$ does not exist.

Note that the converse of the first statement is not true (take $x_n = n^{-1}$, for example).